# Probability of two transitions in Markov Chain

Tags: matlab, probability, markov-chains

I've gotten a grasp on the transition matrices of Markov models, but am still a bit unclear on how to make a series of transitions. Consider the Markov chain at the bottom of the page where `S` = Sunny, `C` = Cloudy, `R` = Rainy.

I have set up this transition matrix in MATLAB

```
A = [0.1 0.2 0.7; 0.4 0.3 0.3; 0.2 0.6 0.2]

    0.1000    0.2000    0.7000
    0.4000    0.3000    0.3000
    0.2000    0.6000    0.2000
```

Now to look up the probability of a transition, I made the following variables for convenience

```
>> S = 1
>> R = 2
>> C = 3
```

You can find the probability of a single transition just by looking it up from the table, for example from Rainy today to Sunny tomorrow would be

```
>> A(R,S)
ans = 0.4000
```

**Question**

I'm having a hard time understanding how to do a series of transitions. For example, if today is Sunny, what is the chance that two days from now it will be Cloudy? (so basically two transitions) I was thinking

```
>> A(S,S)*A(S,C) + A(S,R)*A(R,C) + A(S,C)*A(C,C)
ans = 0.2700
```

Basically I found all possible transitions that could end up at Cloudy from Sunny. Although cumbersome, is that the correct way to go about it?

[image]

Comment: Just square the matrix.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That is really clever, thanks! Can that trend be extrapolated? For example, could I find the probability of ending up in a state after three transitions by cubing the matrix, and so forth?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry, I didn't see your comment...

Comment: @Cyber Yes, that's the idea. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code `A(S,S)*A(S,C) + A(S,R)*A(R,C) + A(S,C)*A(C,C)` (i.e. sum over all possible intermediate states, or [Chapman-Kolmogorov equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Transient_evolution)) is just matrix multiplication:

```
A(S,:)*A(:,C)
```

In general, `A2 = A^2` gives the probabilty of all such double transitions, and `An = A^n` is the probability of `n`-order transitions (see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Example)). So `A2(S,C)` is the probability of two days after today being cloudy if today it's sunny.